# Add new local user to jenkins with Active Directory Configured

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I Installed the Active Directory Plugin and users from the domain can access to the jenkins.

Now I need to create new user but this user can't be in the domain so it need to be local user or something.

Is it possible while the Active Directory is enabled in the Access Control ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

You can make something yourself with [Script Security plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Realm). But then you need to manually script AD/LDAP authentication through that script, plus add the exception for your new user